# What is Wolfram's equivalent of Maple's algsubs?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, semantic-matching

Maple has two primary substitution functions.

- [subs](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=subs) - which is similar to `ReplaceAll` in WL.
- [algsubs](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=algsubs) - which does replacement but takes into account the algebraic rules of the underlying expression.

Please look over the examples on algsubs document page. What function in Wolfram language achieve the same algebraic substitutions?

Comment: `Simplify` is similar, but not equivalent… The main difference is it cannot handle the examples under _Truncating polynomials_ section.

Comment: `PolynomialReduce` would be at the top of the Usual Suspects list (maybe next to Keyser Soze).

Comment: it's not exactly equivalent, but check out `Eliminate` as well!